# Difference in D3 Data Displays

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can somebody tell me why [my code](https://codepen.io/myoung63/pen/ZxEzoQ?editors=0010) is displaying the data coordinates differently than [here](https://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/e3b8b7c2ca4787f77d78f58d41c3da91)? There's an extra circle at the origin of the SVG, and the other circle only follows one line (the black line in the linked CodePen).
*Edit: There's a red line underneath the black one. Switch the "I" slider or hit the "New Exercise" button*

I know the source I'm pulling from is parsing a CSV file, but I'm sure it can be done the way I'm trying to do it. I appreciate any help I can get!

*EDIT: It works if I switch
`var lines = document.getElementsByClassName("line");` to

`var lines = document.getElementsByClassName("line")[0];`

and adjust code accordingly, but then the text renders fuzzily.*

*EDIT: I WILL VENMO YOU $20 FOR A FIX BY TONIGHT.*

Here's the data display function:

```
function visualize(datum) {
    datum = data;
    console.log("Datum", datum);
    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
        .attr("class", "mouse-line")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px")
        .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName("line");

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
        .data(datum)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 7)
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px")
        .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10, 4)")
        .style("font-size", "13px");

    mouseG.append("svg:rect")
        .attr("width", xScale(datum[datum.length - 1].x) - xScale(datum[0].x))
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("x", xScale(datum[0].x))
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouseout hide line, circles, and text
            d3.select(".mouse-line")
                .style("opacity", "0");
            d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
                .style("opacity", "0");
            d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
                .style("opacity", "0");
        })
        .on("mouseover", function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
            d3.select(".mouse-line")
                .style("opacity", "1");
            d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
                .style("opacity", "1");
            d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
                .style("opacity", "1");
        })
        .on("mousemove", function() { // mouse moving over canvas
            var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
            d3.select(".mouse-line")
                .attr("d", function() {
                    var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
                    d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
                    return d;
                });

            d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                    var beginning = 0,
                            end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                            target,
                            pos;

                    while (true){
                        target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                        pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
                        if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                                break;
                        }
                        if (pos.x > mouse[0]) {
                            end = target;
                        }
                        else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) {
                            beginning = target;
                        } else {
                            break; //position found
                        }
                    }

                    d3.select(this).select('text')
                        .text((xScale.invert(pos.x) - 2).toFixed(2) + ", " + yScale.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

                    return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y +")";
                });
        });
}
```

Comment: Here is a hint: you don't have *an extra circle*, you have dozens of them! Also, since that's a Lineweaver-Burk, it's supposed to have just one line, isn't that correct? Where is the other line?

Comment: Definitely a useful hint. I'm not sure where they're spawning from in that case. There's a red line underneath the black one. Switch the "I" slider or hit the "New Exercise" button

Comment: Ok, now I see the extra line. It's a good idea editing your question to add this information.

Comment: Done. Do you know why so many circles are spawning?

Comment: Yes, I do: `datum` is an array of 88 elements. Therefore, you're creating 88 groups with 88 circles.

Comment: I added an edit about a "fix" that looks like it has more to do with the `lines` variable. I'm still trying to find a better solution, but do you see a clear-cut solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172720/discussion-between-in-circ-and-gerardo-furtado).